# Time Dependent Workflow Actions After Sandbox Refresh

Tags: workflow, email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

We have some workflow rules that use Time Dependent Workflow Actions to send an email alert a few weeks after a record is created.  Will production pending actions that are replicated to a sandbox following a sandbox refresh be executed in the sandbox?

For example:

- On March 23 I create an Opportunity with a close date of April 15 in production
- A workflow rule fires and schedules an email alert to be sent on April 15.
- On March 27 I refresh my full copy sandbox from production and set the access level to "All email" under Email Administration > Deliverability
- Between March 27 and April 15 no changes are made to either the record or the workflow rule in my full copy sandbox

Will the email alert be sent from my full copy sandbox on April 15?

Answer (score 0):

While I don't exactly know the answer, before you turn on Deliverability in the full sandbox, you can check the pending workflow queue (Monitor > Time-Based Workflow). If you click Search and find nothing, then the workflows were not copied.